# Assigning values to a slider

Tags: reactjs, react-native

OK, this is weird. My API should throw the string "24,36,48" - and it actually does, my variable is assigned that value. I need to split it in three parts: A, B, C (sometimes it has four values - that's why I have a variable D). So, I split the string like this

```
 `const [termA, termB, termC, termD] = values.split(',');
      setvA(Number(termA));
      setvB(Number(termB));
      setvC(Number(termC));
      setvD(Number(termD));`
```

and every one of them gets the value it is supposed to get. The problem is that on the slider, if I have the values 24,36,48 the slider gets 36,48,NaN.

Below is my whole code.

This is the API call:

```
  const [sliderValue, setsliderValue] = useState();
  const [sliderValue2, setsliderValue2] = useState(A);
  const [A, setvA] = useState();
  const [B, setvB] = useState();
  const [C, setvC] = useState();
  const [D, setvD] = useState();
  const [pterms, setpterms] = useState([]);
  const valuesFromApi = [ A,B,C,D];
  const [Value, setValue] = useState(pterms[A]);
  useEffect(() => { 
 async  function BCcontroller() {
  const vCreationUser = 6;
  const vSolicitudeId = 8;
  const { data } = await ForceApi.post(`/ConsultBCController.php`, {vSolicitudeId, vCreationUser});
  const values = data.terms;
  setpterms(data.terms);
  //console.log(values);
  const [termA, termB, termC, termD] = values.split(',');
  setvA(Number(termA));
  setvB(Number(termB));
  setvC(Number(termC));
  setvD(Number(termD));
  // console.log(values);
}
 BCcontroller();
}, );

if (!A) return null;
```

This is my slider:

```
<View style={{alignItems: 'stretch', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Slider 
                  maximumValue={D > 0 ? 4: 3 }
                  minimumValue={1}
                  step={1}
                  value={valuesFromApi.indexOf(Value)}
                 onValueChange={index => setValue(valuesFromApi[index])} 
                />
                <View style={styles.plazos}>
                  <Text style={styles.plazo1}>{A} meses</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.plazo2}>{B} meses</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.plazo3}>{C} meses</Text>
                  {D > 0 ? <Text style={styles.plazo3}>{D} meses</Text>: null }
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.slideText}>Su credito por:  ${A}MXN</Text>
                <Text style={styles.slideText}>Usted recibe:    ${A}MXN</Text>
                <Text style={styles.slideText}>A un plazo de:  {Value} meses</Text>

                <Text style={styles.PaymentText}>Su pago: ${A}.00 MXN</Text>
              </View>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the values of `Value` and `index`? You need to provide the full code. Create a minimum sample project on https://codesandbox.io/s/ if possible.

Comment: the value of value is  `const [Value, setValue] = useState(pterms[0]);` and pterms is the string 24,36,48

Comment: `valuesFromApi.indexOf(Value)` will return `0` if the match is at index 0 but your `Slider`'s `minimumValue` is `1`?

Comment: i tried to put as minvalue A but there is an error that says `invariant violation, input range must be monotonically non decreasing 24,3` also the values of the slider are 1, 2,3 and 4 if D >0, so its doesnt matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only have "24,36,48" from the API, then in here:

```js
const [termA, termB, termC, termD] = values.split(',');
```

termD will be undefined, which Number(termD) will return NaN (Not a number). I suggest you should have a default value for termD like:

```js
setvD(typeof termD === 'string' ? Number(termD) : 0); // 0 can be changed to your preferred value
```

Also, when D is now NaN, the comparision D > 0 will always be false, which makes the maximum value to be 3

UPDATE: take a look at your minimum value (currently 1). However arrays index from 0 in JS. So indexing from 1 to 3 will be B, C and D. If you change minimum value to 0 and maximum value to D>0?3:2, you will get correct value

Comment: well yeah now i dont have any NaN number, but now the slider prints 36,48, 0 instead of 24,36,48

Comment: im not sure if the problem is here on my  onchangevalue
`value={valuesFromApi.indexOf(Value)}
onValueChange={index => setValue(valuesFromApi[index])} `

Comment: @user10625391 I noticed another issue and updated my answer, please take a look